# Xcode IME - Quick shortcut to get parameter type of method call?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In Xcode, i'm always trying to figure out what parameter type to pass, for this example: for 'attribute' given in this code:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: someView,
    attribute: .CenterY,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: view,
    attribute: .CenterY,
    multiplier: 1,
    constant: 0
)
```

Would of course be `NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY`

Is there a way to quickly figure out the parameter class type of `.CenterY` in attribute without using the <kbd>⌘</kbd> button on the `NSLayoutConstraint` and reading out the func init call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are typing `NSLayoutConstraint(` you get suggested autocompletion:

[image]

Then after you click Enter you get into the following situation (where you clearly see all the parameter types)

[image]

If, however, you already have `NSLayoutConstraint()` written somewhere in full (like in your question), all you have to do is to click on `item`,`attribute`, etc and you will be able to see the function definition in the Quick Help Inspector (if it is selected)

[image]

there you can easily figure out the parameter class type of `.CenterY`.

If this isn't what you need, can you please explain in more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, this is perfect. Showing QuickHelpInspector was the key thing I was missing, and providing another way of showing the types was excellent. Thank you!